# Error jq: invalid JSON text passed to --argjson

Tags: json, jq

Consider

```
$ keys='[["key1","a"],["key2","b"]]' jq -c --argjson keys "$keys" '.[] | [getpath($keys[])]' <<<$'[{"key1":{"a":1},"key2":{"b":2}}] [{"key1":{"a":3},"key2":{"b":4}}]'
```

I expect output

```
[1,2]
[3,4]
```

But I seem to doing something wrong when defining `argjson`. I get error:

```
jq: invalid JSON text passed to --argjson
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are either missing a semi-colon (or equivalent), or misunderstanding shell variables.

1. With the semicolon:

```
keys='[["key1","a"],["key2","b"]]' ; jq -c -n --argjson keys "$keys" '$keys'
```

2. Using shell variables:

```
keys='[["key1","a"],["key2","b"]]' jq -c -n 'env.keys | fromjson'
```